# PROC SQL/ SQL multiple joins by first row

Tags: sql, join, sas, proc-sql

I have 3 datasets and I hope to join them by first row because they are in different levels.
I assigned the base dataset to be (the other 2 will be left joined to the base dataset):

```
item  state  county  by_county

Apple  MD     aa      4
Apple  DC     bb      3
Apple  DC     cc      2
Pear   VA     cc      6
```

2nd dataset:

```
item state  by_state

Apple  MD    4
Apple  DC    5
Pear   VA    6
```

3rd dataset:

```
item        by_item

Apple        9
Pear         6
```

I'm hoping to join the datasets to have output as the following:

```
item   state  county  by_county   by_state  by_item

Apple   MD     aa     4            4        9
Apple   DC     bb     3            5
Apple   DC     cc     2       
Pear    VA     cc     6            6        6
```

You can order by item,state and county to determine the first row.
This join is in SAS environment, thus partition by may not work. (I'm not sure)

I cannot use left join because I need to retain only one record by level. For example, the output dataset retain missings because I only need one item count (by_item) for all states or counties.

For some reason people insisted that I should post the query that I knew it will not deliver the right outcome:

```
select a*,b*,c*
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b
on a.item = b.item and a.state = b.state
left join table3 as c
on a.item = c.item;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I tried left join, and I do not know how to stop the items from repeating because of different levels in different datasets.

Comment: Then post your query so people can help you fix it.

Comment: "For some reason people insisted that I should post the query that I knew it will not deliver the right outcome".  This is the purpose of this website.  You post your broken query, you tell what you want to accomplish, people will help you fix your query.  If you don't post your query, how do you expect people to help?

Comment: Why SQL? Why not just use normal SAS code instead?

Comment: @Tom yeah I wouldn’t mind that XD saw your response on SAS community

Answer (score 1):

As I think you know to get the values without the requirement of only the first like this:

```
SELECT base.item, base.state,  base.county,  base.by_county,   state.by_state,  item.by_item
FROM base
LEFT JOIN state on base.item = state.item and base.state = state.state
LEFT JOIN item on base.item = item.item
```

To modify this to just pick the first item we use windowing functions -- first add them in

```
SELECT base.item, base.state,  base.county,  
       base.by_county, 
       state.by_state,  ROW_NUMBER(partition by base.by_state order by  item,state and county) as RN_S, 
       item.by_item,  ROW_NUMBER(partition by base.by_item order by  item,state and county) as RN_I,
FROM base
LEFT JOIN state on base.item = state.item and base.state = state.state
LEFT JOIN item on base.item = item.item
```

Then we add in the filter:

```
SELECT item, state, county, by_county,
       CASE WHEN RN_S = 1 THEN by_state ELSE NULL END AS by_state,
       CASE WHEN RN_I = 1 THEN by_item  ELSE NULL END AS by_item
FROM
(
  SELECT base.item, base.state,  base.county,  
       base.by_county, 
       state.by_state,  ROW_NUMBER(partition by base.by_state order by  item,state and county) as RN_S, 
       item.by_item,  ROW_NUMBER(partition by base.by_item order by  item,state and county) as RN_I,
  FROM base
  LEFT JOIN state on base.item = state.item and base.state = state.state
  LEFT JOIN item on base.item = item.item 
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to consider the problem.
What about expecting the target table as the following, so it does not even break the meaning of the value.

```
    item   state  county  value  

    Apple   MD     aa     4      
    Apple   DC     bb     3
    Apple   DC     cc     2
    Pear    VA     cc     6       

    Apple   MD     ANY    4        
    Apple   DC     ANY    5  
    Pear    VA     ANY    6  

    Apple   ANY    ANY    9   
    Pear    ANY    ANY    6
```

The above result can be simply achieve with `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT 
   item, 
   state, 
   county, 
   by_county as value
 FROM tbl_level3) 
 UNION ALL
(SELECT 
   item, 
   state, 
   "Any" as county, 
   by_state as value
 FROM tbl_level2) 
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT 
   item, 
   "Any" as state, 
   "Any" as county, 
   by_item as value
 FROM tbl_level1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, that is a very creative thought, but I would like to keep my dataset small..

Comment: May be you can reduce the table size by reducing the number of columns.
Replace 3 columns `by_county`, `by_sate` and `by_item` with a single column.
Let me update my solution with that.

Comment: I need to keep the value seperate by_county , by_state, by_item because I will later use that dataset in excel pivot table. Excel function only knows how to sum by column...haha life is a struggle.

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible SAS solution to this problem 
first we need to join all tables together. A new column is created (skey) which is simply the combination of item and state fields. rows are sorted by item, state, county.

```
proc sql;
create table all as 
select t1.*, t2.by_state, t3.by_item, catx('||', t1.item, t1.state) as skey
from t1 left join t2
    on t1.item = t2.item and t1.state = t2.state
        left join t3 
            on t1.item = t3.item
order by item, state, county 
;
quit;
```

then the first row for each state and item is marked as 1 only. this is done by adding a column "n". the idea is to find the first row (similar to row_number statement in native sql language)

```
data all_1;
set all;
by skey;
if first.skey then n=1;
else n='.';
run;
```

similar to the previous part, the first row for each item is marked as 1.

```
data all_2;
set all_1;
by item;
if first.item then m=1;
else m='.';
run;
```

finally the desired result is obtained by binary multiplication of first row marks and by_item and by_state values as below:

```
proc sql;
create table final as 
select item, state, county, by_county, by_state * n as by_state, by_item * m as by_item 
from all_2
;
quit;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to combine the datasets, so you need to `JOIN` the 3 tables.  If you want one row per item, then you have to aggregate it.  The query below should produce one row per item.

```
SELECT item, SUM(by_country) AS by_country_sum, SUM(by_state) AS by_state_sum, SUM(by_item) AS by_item_sum
FROM (
    your query
) a
GROUP BY item;
```

Comment: I cannot just group by item, I need it to be by item and state as well..There are different levels.

Comment: I based my query on what you said here "I only need one item count (by_item) for all states or counties".  So what exactly you want?  Please edit your question with clear explanation.

Comment: I read the "For example" part.  But it still implies you want one row per item.